# Autowiring collections with IoC

Tags: collections, inversion-of-control, autowired

Anyone know if there exists any IoC container that can handle this:

Given:

```
ISomeInterfce<T> where T : Entity

Impl1 : ISomeInterfce<Entity1>

Impl2 : ISomeInterfce<Entity1>

Impl3 : ISomeInterfce<Entity2>

Impl4 : ISomeInterfce<Entity2>
```

I want to be able to auto wire my system and be able to resolve like this

```
IoC.ResolveAll(typeof(ISomeInterfce<Entity1>))
```

and get a collection back
of all implementations of `ISomeInterfce<Entity1>`

Answer (score 1):

[Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) (my favourite IoC container) supports this feature, check out: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Collections for details.

Comment: Thanks looks promising. But can you combine Autofac.Collections with Autofac.Autowiring ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure but I would presume it would work that way?